# SQL TRIGGER (Compilation errors)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, compiler-errors

I'm writing a trigger in SQL for the first time. Can anyone please tell me what am I writing wrong in this code?

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Course_Allocation_After_Update
2  AFTER UPDATE
3  ON COURSE_ALLOCATION
4  FOR EACH ROW
5  DECLARE
6  v_user_id varchar2(20);
7  BEGIN
8  --Finding User who is performing the update in the table
9  SELECT USER
10  INTO v_user_id
11  FROM dual;
12  --Inserting Information Into Staging Table (Log Table)
13  IF UPDATING(STU_ID)   
14  THEN
15  INSERT INTO STAGING_TABLE
16  (user_id,old_value,new_value,date_when_updated,time_when_udated)
17  VALUES
18  (v_user_id,:old.STU_ID,:new.STU_ID,sysdate,systime)
19  END IF;
20  END;
21  /
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

These are the errors:
11/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
14/53    PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
16/4     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
following:
if

Comment: fyi, it's a PL/SQL trigger. PL/SQL is the programming language. And there's no law that says you have to CODE IN UPPERCASE. Personally I find it hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your forget semicolon after insert clause;
2. `systime` - not exists in Oracle . `SYSDATE` - already contain information about time. If you want to separate it you may use `trunc(sysdate)` - return only date and to_char(sysdate,'HH24:MI:SS') - return string with time. Or may be you mean `systimestamp`
3. (optional) why you need to select user into variable? Just use it as value

My version code of trigger:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Course_Allocation_After_Update
 AFTER UPDATE
 ON COURSE_ALLOCATION
 FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
 v_user_id varchar2(20);
 BEGIN
 --Inserting Information Into Staging Table (Log Table)
 IF UPDATING(STU_ID)   
 THEN
 INSERT INTO STAGING_TABLE
 (user_id,old_value,new_value,date_when_updated)
 VALUES
 (USER,:old.STU_ID,:new.STU_ID,sysdate);
 END IF;
 END;
 /
```

Comment: Thankyou for pointing these errors out. I've made some changes. But still there are errors.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Course_Allocation_After_Update
 AFTER UPDATE
 ON COURSE_ALLOCATION
 FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
 v_STU_ID varchar2(20);
 BEGIN
 --Finding User who is performing the update in the table
 SELECT STU_ID
 INTO v_STU_ID
 FROM COURSE_ALLOCATION;

 --Inserting Information Into Staging Table (Log Table)
 IF UPDATING(STU_ID) THEN
 INSERT INTO STAGING_TABLE
 (user_id,old_value,new_value,date_when_updated)
 VALUES
 (USER,:old.v_STU_ID,:new.v_STU_ID,sysdate);
 END IF;
 END;
 /

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Course_Allocation_After_Update 
AFTER UPDATE ON COURSE_ALLOCATION 
referencing old as old new as new
FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE 
    v_STU_ID varchar2(20); 

BEGIN --Finding User who is performing the update in the table 
    SELECT STU_ID 
    INTO v_STU_ID 
    FROM COURSE_ALLOCATION; 

    --Inserting Information Into Staging Table (Log Table) 
    IF UPDATING('STU_ID') 
    THEN 
        INSERT INTO STAGING_TABLE (user_id,old_value,new_value,date_when_updated) 
        VALUES (USER,:old.v_STU_ID,:new.v_STU_ID,sysdate); 
    END IF; 
 END; 
 /
```

Futher it seems to me that:

```
SELECT STU_ID 
INTO v_STU_ID 
FROM COURSE_ALLOCATION;
```

can not be good, because you will select all the stu_id records from the course_allocation table.  And that will give you a "too_many_rows" error.
How does the course_allocation table look like?